# Nodejs Mongodb Fetch data between date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have saved my `date` as timestamp, using the below logic:

```
var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
timestamp =145161061
```

Can any one help me out with the query?

I need to find records between dates and my date is stored in timestamp format as shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have specified the type of the field to be date, then even if you store the date by giving the time stamp, it will get stored as Date.

To do a range query on date you can simply do something like  this:

```
db.events.find({"event_date": {
$gte: ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
$lt: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),}})
```

But then if you have specified it as Number, then you can simply do a range query on the number like this :

```
db.events.find({"event_date": {
$gte: 145161061,
$lt: 145178095,}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try kind of this query:

```
var startTime = 145161061;
var endTime = 149161061;
Books.find({
    created_at: {
        $gt: startTime,
        $lt: endTime
    } 
});
```